# Error in unit testing (karma). There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngbPopover"

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

Am using the below ngbPopover in my angular page and while writing Unit testing for it. It throws me an compile error. Like below

There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngbPopover"
                      (click)="p1.open()" [ERROR ->]#p1="ngbPopover">

```
    <span placement="bottom"  [ngbPopover]="popContent"  triggers="manual"
          (click)="p1.open()" #p1="ngbPopover">
    </span>




    import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { NotificationsService as ToasterService } from 'angular2-notifications';
import { NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { testComponent } from './test.component';

describe('testComponent', () => {
  let component: testComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<testComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [testComponent],
      imports: [ FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule  ],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    const toasterServiceStub = {
      create: () => ({})
    };
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [testComponent],
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
      providers: [
        { provide: ToasterService, useValue: toasterServiceStub }
      ]
    });
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(testComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(testComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

If I remove that #p1 from html, my unit testing gets compiled. But not sure why that causes an error. Please help me out

Comment: Please share the entire test in question. If the template is being parsed that means you're setting up an integration test, not an actual unit test. So you're most likely missing an import OR you want to rewrite your spec setup to represent an actual unit test.

Comment: @PhilippMeissner I have added the spec file above. Hope it gives some clarity now.

Comment: What is your desired behaviour? Unit test, as in: The DOM does not get loaded. Or an integration test where the DOM is being fully built up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want a unit test where the DOM is not being built up, then go with the following setup:

```
describe('testComponent', () => {
  let component: testComponent;

  // Note that you have to initialize the component only *once* via the TestBed, not multiples times as you did.
  beforeEach(() => {
    const toasterServiceStub = {
      create: () => ({}),
    };

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        testComponent,
        {provide: ToasterService, useValue: toasterServiceStub},
      ],
    });

    component = TestBed.get(testComponent);
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

If your desired test is supposed to be an integration test where you want to make sure that the HTML is being parsed properly your implementation **initializes the component too often** and **misses** at least the **import** for Ngb.

```
describe('testComponent', () => {
  let component: testComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<testComponent>;

  // // Only configure the testing module once, not multiple times.
  // beforeEach(async(() => {
  //   TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  //     declarations: [testComponent],
  //     imports: [ FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule  ],
  //   }).compileComponents();
  // }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    const toasterServiceStub = {
      create: () => ({})
    };

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [testComponent],
      imports: [FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, NgbModule], // Here you were missing the NgbModule. You may also just import the sub-modules you're explicitely using (such as pagination)
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
      providers: [
        { provide: ToasterService, useValue: toasterServiceStub }
      ]
    });
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(testComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();

    // You do not need to do this twice.
    // fixture = TestBed.createComponent(testComponent);
    // component = fixture.componentInstance;
    // fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Either implementation should work for your case. The difference between these implementations is that the first one does not build up the entire HTML DOM, whereas the second implementation does.
For the first one to work all modules that are being used inside the HTML need to be present.
The second implementation does basically only initialize the component and its injected dependencies.

Comment: Thanks! it seems to be working without DOM. will probably check the second piece of code as well.

Comment: The first example basically only calls `new testComponent(toasterServiceStub)`. That's why the HTML is not important at all.

Comment: if `testComponent` is a component in first part isn't it be under declarations? Is there a specific reason putting under providers. Providers are for `services`, right ?

Comment: Not necessarily. The providers array you pass to TestBed is for whatever class you want instantiated automagically by the framework. In this case, it is the component. If you were to put it into the declarations, its HTML would be build and processed as well. Considering a unit test was all that was required, no HTML was needed thus an instantiated class is enough for testing.